# Перестановки java

Tags: char, java

Есть массив char. Необходимо выполнить случайную перестановку.
при этом элементы не должны повторяться.
Допустим есть массив {1,2,3,4} после перестановки должно быть {2,3,4,1}

Comment: Random по индексам элементов массива вам в помощь.

Comment: при этом элементы не должны повторяться.
Допустим есть массив {1,2,3,4} после перестановки должно быть {2,3,4,1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементарно, Ватсон. Случайно выбираем 2 индекса массива, затем меняем их местами:

```
Random r=new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int index1, index2, array[]={1,2,3,4};
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {   //iterating over elements
        index1=r.nextInt(array.length);
        index2=r.nextInt(array.length);
        int value=array[index1];
        array[index1]=array[index2];
        array[index2]=value;
}
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
     System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

каждому элементу массива генерируете в соответствие случайное число, на пример,  от 0 до 1 000 000. после этого сортируете полученные числа в порядке возрастания, а с ними и индексы элементов массива.  
На пример:  
[a,b,c,d] -> сгенерировать для каждого элемента случайное число -> [123,23423,3452,12] -> упорядочить массив с числами по возрастанию -> [12,123,3452,23423] -> а с ним и индексы элементов массива, элементы которого нужно разбросать -> [d,a,c,b]